# Can't add Facebook account in online accounts

Tags: gnome, online-accounts

I got a problem that online accounts pop up can't handle Facebook login.

It shows like this:

[image: screenshot of problem]

It says that the pop up window too small to do login.

Does someone have a solution about it?